# Unexpected Token . while verifying the working of gulp

Tags: javascript, bash, gulp

I picked up this book "Learning JavaScript - Add Sparkle and Life to you web pages.

I reached the section where it tells a bit about git, gulp. I don't know anything more than what I've got from the book so far.

So I created a gulp file, as asked by the author. The gulp file contains following code.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
//Gulp dependencies go here
gulp.task('default', function)() {
//Gulp tasks go here
});
```

After that, it asks to verify that the gulp is working successfully now by typing `gulp`in command line( I am using GIT bash. No idea how is it different, but I really don't want to get overwhelmed, hence I am sticking with the book.).

I got the following error.

```
    $ gulp

c:\Users\lespa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\node_modules\array-differ\index.js:2
module.exports = (arr, ...values) => {
                       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\lespa\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-util\lib\PluginError.js:2:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Can anybody help me?

Thank You

Comment: What is the version of your `Node`?

Comment: Hi, @str brought it to my notice. I was using an older version. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Node.js 5.11.0 or later to [support the spread operator (`...`)](http://node.green/#spread-------operator).